# JavaScript dynamically set img src to HTML5 uploaded file

Tags: javascript, html, jszip

I am using the [JSZip](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/) library to extract uploaded epub files. I can successfully iterate through it and display the name of the file within the library with:

```
zipEntry.name;
```

And I can find the cover.jpg file with string comparisons. How can I set the source of a image on my html page to that cover?
I have tried:

```
src=zipEntry;
```

and

```
src=zipEntry.name;
```

Is it even possible? Is there a  easy way to do it with jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried putting an empty image on a page

```
<img id="testimg" />
```

and then using this javascript code to show a PNG image from a zip file:

```
var zipEntry = zip.file('test.png');
$('#testimg')[0].src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + base64_encode(zipEntry.asBinary());
```

This worked for me. See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whr8z/6/) for a demo of the working code.

You will need the function `base64_encode()` (from [phpjs.org](http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_encode/)):

```
function base64_encode (data) {
  // phpjs.org
  var b64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
  var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0,
    ac = 0,
    enc = "",
    tmp_arr = [];

  if (!data) {
    return data;
  }

  do { // pack three octets into four hexets
    o1 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
    o2 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
    o3 = data.charCodeAt(i++);

    bits = o1 << 16 | o2 << 8 | o3;

    h1 = bits >> 18 & 0x3f;
    h2 = bits >> 12 & 0x3f;
    h3 = bits >> 6 & 0x3f;
    h4 = bits & 0x3f;

    // use hexets to index into b64, and append result to encoded string
    tmp_arr[ac++] = b64.charAt(h1) + b64.charAt(h2) + b64.charAt(h3) + b64.charAt(h4);
  } while (i < data.length);

  enc = tmp_arr.join('');

  var r = data.length % 3;

  return (r ? enc.slice(0, r - 3) : enc) + '==='.slice(r || 3);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. The "magic" is in that base64_encode() function.

Answer (score 1):

You need know host on which located image, not only image name. Or have image data in base64.

```
load image from external (or local) host:
<img src="{HOST}/cover.jpg"/>

base64:
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,R0lGODdhMAAw....." />
```

Comment: I tried the base 64 approach but the problem is that the library only has a Uint8Array property and I tried to convert without any luck. I do not understand your first solution using {HOST} can you please explain.

Answer (score 0):

hi i am using this and user json array image path instead of source using {"+http//......+"}

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
document.getElementById("five_star").innerHTML = "<img alt='' src='images/activestar.png'>";
}
```